# Notepad++ how to select multiple text blocks that always start and finish with the same word?

Tags: regex, notepad++, selection

i'm editing a huge text file and I want to delete multiple blocks of copy in this text file..

the blocks always start with START and end with END

is this possible?

I've used search & replace

and ^START starts ok, but I'm not sure how to select copy upto END

Answer (score 1):

Use follow regex:

```
(?s)START.*?END
```

It matches with blocks which:

- (?s) enable single line mode to search over few lines
- start with `START`
- end with `END`
- don't contain `END` inside block.

Comment: thx for the quick reply, but if i use that.. i get the message "Can't find the text: "Start.*?End"

Comment: @kikker improved my answer

Comment: get the same thing Can't find the text :"(?s)Start.*?End"

Comment: @kikker could you provide text?

Comment: @kikker this regex is case sensitive. Does your text contains `START` or `Start`?

Answer (score 0):

```
START[\s\S]*?END
```

Try this.This will select multiple lines as well.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/4

Comment: worked! with regex search mode on of course! thanks!